# Scan image and read context on mobile browser using JS

Tags: javascript, html, web-frontend

I need to get the printed tag number by scanning a tag using **JS on browser**. It's like, the system (web app) should be able to **get the credit card number by scanning credit card using mobile's camera** instead of manual fill-up.

Someone can help me to get resolved this please?

Comment: Find a way do to OCR using JS/WASM (good luck doing it yourself) or upload the image to a service that does OCR.

Comment: Welcome to the site  - and note that questions should typically have more details to work on, and in particular [show research effort](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on your part. What have you tried? What worked and what did not? Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: @tucuxi , First I just need to know is this possible with pure JS. Because I'm a fresher for JS. And what I tried is, As the first step, I wrote a code to capture image (https://github.com/aeturnum-tharindu/scan-image/blob/master/cam.html). It works on PC, but mobile doesn't support. What would be the issue?

Comment: Write a new question explaining what you tried, how you tested it, how it failed and on which mobile phones you expected it to work. Complex code is built little by little. Mostly everything is possible with code, but some things are very hard.

Answer (score 2):

The question is very rough in terms of details, so here is a possible outline of a solution:

1. Write JS to request permission to use the phones' camera (which will probably default to the frontal one). Show images as they are being captured so that users can place the card in the best lighting and in the required rectangle.
2. Write JS to process images and attempt to recognize the card number. You can either transmit images to a server for recognition (uses significant bandwidth), or use an existing library to build on. There is [OpenCV for Javascript](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/df7/tutorial_js_table_of_contents_setup.html), and people have [built CC# recognition](https://github.com/tonywry/Credit-Card-Number-Recognition) on OpenCV before.